# I want to change string values in DataFrame (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to change string values in DataFrame!

My data have 25000 rows, and 2 columns like this:

[image: My data]

I want to change id column values to not have " "

ex) "12311_10" => 12311_10

How can i do this?? help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) - if `"` is necessary remove:

```
df['id'] = df['id'].str.strip('"')
```

Or if necessary remove `''`:

```
df['id'] = df['id'].str.strip("'")
```

Comment: Thank you So much!!!!!! I was searching this answer for 1 hour, but I couldn't search this.....

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `str.replace` to remove the `"`

```
df['id'] = df['id'].str.replace('"','')
```